# using FB.data.query not getting any response back

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the user gender and birth date through the following:

```
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                var query = FB.Data.query('select birthday, gender from user where owner={0}',
                       response.id);

                query.wait(function(rows) {
                    console.log(rows[0].birthday);
                    console.log(rows[0].gender);
                    alert(rows[0].birthday);
                    alert(rows[0].gender);
                });
            });
```

However, I see nothing on the console and there is no alert. Why is this?

Comment: What permissions do you have set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the birthday and gender of an authenticated user (/me) you can just access the User Object like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response.birthday);
    console.log(response.gender);
    alert(response.birthday);
    alert(response.gender);
});
```

If you want the birthday and gender to come from the user table you can't use the "gender" field because it doesn't exist. Use "sex" instead.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  var query = FB.Data.query('select birthday, sex from user where uid={0}', response.id);

   query.wait(function(rows) {
         console.log(rows[0].birthday);
         console.log(rows[0].gender);
         alert(rows[0].birthday);
         alert(rows[0].sex);
        });
});
```

You received no response because you were trying to access a field that doesn't exist.