# Facebook Javascript SDK: Processing Response from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having  trouble understanding how to process the response when you make an API call to facebook.  Should mention that I'm new to javascript.

Say I want to get the mutual friends between me and some user, and then write it to a text box.  I took a shot and ended up with this ...which failed. I'm pretty sure it's because I didn't parse the response, but I can't figure out how. I've seen something like `query.wait(function(rows){` for FQL queries ... but I don't know what that means..so I skipped it.

```
function getMutual(){

    FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+target, function(response) {

            document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML =
            'FQL Information: '+  response +"<br />";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beginning of your callback function `function(response) {`, do either a `debugger;` statement to start debugging in your browser, or you can do a `console.dir(response);` to see the object structure. Half your battle learning javascript is learning how to use some powerful tools that modern browsers now have built in.

Comment: Thanks!. Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Comment: You'll get there.  Takes time.  And for your first javascript project to be integration with Facebook is an amazing choice as both have steep learning curves.

Answer (score 1):

The response will return the following data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "XXX", 
      "id": "YYY"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "ZZZ", 
      "id": "OOO"
    }, 
    ...
}
```

To get the information by JS,
you can iterate the array response.data

for example response.data[0].name return XXX

Comment: Seems simple enough! Out of curiosity, could you explain to me how that query.wait(function(rows) thing works? I saw it in an example for fql...if I'm not making any sense let me know :)

Comment: Yes, most of the response data can read by JS like this. As DMCS mentioned, you can log the response to see the structure, FB documentation doesn't provide much information about the response.

I didn't try the FQL method before, may be you can try to read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773841/using-fb-data-query-not-getting-any-response-back, just a quick search in this site. The query.wait is a callback just like the function(response){} for Graph API. The rows is the array holding the result data